# IDA - Get Jni disassembled functions name

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering, ida

Is there a way to import jni functions name to IDA
IDA just referencing functions offest with a proper name

[image]

I've already tried some python scripts, non of them worked with IDA 7.0
i think they are incompatible with this version of IDA.
https://github.com/trojancyborg/IDA_JNI_Rename
https://github.com/feicong/jni_helper
I also tried to import `jni.h`
https://gist.github.com/Jinmo/048776db75067dcd6c57f1154e65b868